# Frontend validation

Tags: javascript

We have a front end form where users enter the below feed. I would need to validate the text, display a popup if there is a word "Y" instead of "X" after the first ":" and clear the row which has Y in it.

```
20170731_5412_1234:X:Hello:P:James::999999999
20170731_5412_5678:X:Gopal::Varma::999999999
20170731_5412_1234:X:Steve:H:Benton::999999999
20170731_5412_2321:Y:Varme::Dost::999999999
```

For example:
In the above feed the 4th line has "Y" after the first column. I need to display a popup stating the user Varme has Y and it will be cleared. The validation should be performed on multiple rows.

Comment: In what form does the feed come? An array?

Comment: <form id="mycode" name="mycode" method="POST" action="mycode.ext" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 form-group1 ">
<label class="control-label">Enter Input Feed :</label>
              <textarea id="query" name="query" spellcheck="false" textarea onkeyup="foo(this)" placeholder="One CWID per Line - Maximum of 30 lines" class="txtareafeed" required></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100px;" onclick="loadGifImage();">Convert</button>
</div><div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
        </form>

Comment: Hi Anthony, Above is the form used in the code.

Comment: I think your best best is to use string splits. I'll show you what I mean below in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, where you split your text result first on the newline character ("\n") and then by colons:

```
var input,
    cwidRows,
    results,
    i;

// divide input string into an array of strings representing each line
input = stringFromTextArea;
cwidRows = input.split("\n");

// put acceptable results into results array for later use
results = [];
for (i = 0; i < cwidRows; i++) {
    if (cwidRows[i].split(":")[1] !== "Y") results.push(cwidRows[i]);
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! If you have time, please be sure to mark my answer as the "accepted" answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.